# Libgdx: overlaying two images into scene 2D table

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to make a progress bar in LibGdx. I'm using scene 2D to put elements into the screen (is a loading screen). I'm using a table, where I put an image, a label ("loading...") and a progress bar.

The progress bar is composed by two images. My problem is that I cannot overlay the two images. I'm using this code

```
stage.addActor(root);
root.add(image).width(200).height(200);
root.row();
root.add(new Label("Loading...", skin));
root.row();
root.add(progressBarBG).width(600);
root.add(progressBarFG).height(30).width(30);
root.pack();
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

But the progressBarBG and progressBarFG are draw one followed by the other. It is a way to put one over the other one?

ProgressBarBG and ProgressBarFG are loaded from a texture atlas. Root is a Table.

Thanks.

Comment: You could use `ProgressBar` (http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ProgressBar.html)

Comment: It was my frst try, but I cannot put it to work. I cannot adjust the size of the knob, that is huge. Do you know an example of use?

Comment: Unfortunatly not and i never used it myself, but take a look at all those `Drawable`s inside the `ProgressBarStyle` class. The `Knob` should be at the position of the current value. Try to use different `Drawable`s for that `Knob`. As much as i understood you want to have a `ProgrsssBar`, that gets filled with the progress. So maybe the `knobAfter` or `disabledBackground` is what you are looking for. Try them out and let me know^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Springrbua mentioned, it's best to use `ProgressBar` for this.

Though, to answer your question, you can use a `Group` to overlap images with scene2d. Simply add all of the images to one group, then add that group to the desired parent. If you need to offset any of the images in the group, you can use `image.setPosition(offsetX, offsetY)`. Here's an example for your case:

```
stage.addActor(root);
root.add(image).width(200).height(200);
root.row();
root.add(new Label("Loading...", skin));
root.row();
//Use groups to overlay multiple images
Group group = new Group();
progressBarBG.setWidth(600);
progressBarFG.setSize(30, 30);
group.addActor(progressBarBG);
group.addActor(progressBarFG);
root.add(group);
root.pack();
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

Comment: Thanks. Finally I understood how to use progress bar, but overlapping images is a feature that I would use soon or later.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to place a diamond image over a box image:

```
Image boxImage = new Image(Assets.instance.gifts.box);
Image diamondImage = new Image(Assets.instance.gifts.diamond);
Stack diamondBox = new Stack();
diamondBox.addActor(boxImage);
diamondBox.addActor(diamondImage);
tbl.add(diamondBox).width(20).height(20);
tbl.row();
```